# Unexpected behavior of set.seed() in conjunction with .Random.seed in R?

Tags: r, random

I stumbled across this unexpected behavior (to me), which is likely due to my misuse and/or misunderstanding of `.Random.seed`.

```
set.seed(1234)  # This is for reproducibility
s1 <- .Random.seed
set.seed(s1)
s2 <- .Random.seed
runif(1)
s3 <- .Random.seed
set.seed(s3)
s4 <- .Random.seed
all(s2==s4)  # TRUE
```

The part I don't understand is the last line. How can the seed set have "returned" to `s2`, that is, to the set before `runif(1)` was called?

I understand that `.Random.seed` saves the seed set for the uniform random-number generator, but it was my understanding that I could also use it as an input for the `set.seed()` function.

Comment: `set.seed()` is only meant to take a single number. It's not meant to take the value from `.Random.seed`. When you pass in a vector, it will only take the first number. Note that `s1[1]==s3[1]` (403) so it's the same as calling `set.seed(403)` both times. You can see that `all(s1==s2)==FALSE` but `set.seed(s1); runif(1); set.seed(s2); runif(1)` you get the same numbers back. Rather than using `set.seed()`, you can just assign to `.Random.seed<-` directly if you want.

Comment: @MrFlick that should probably be an answer, rather than a comment

Comment: @MrFlick Thank you, that was it. I thought set.seed() would use the whole vector as first argument, and not only its first element. I would have expected a warning of some sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the integer vector `.Random.seed` with `set.seed`. Only the first integer will be used. Indeed, the RNG state you saved is the same as when calling `set.seed(403)`, which is the first element of `.Random.seed`.

If you are sure that you have a *valid* seed vector, then you can assign it to `.Random.seed`. However, you are probably better of to use `rngtools::RNGseed()`, since that does at least some basic error checking:

```
set.seed(1234)  # This is for reproducibility
s1 <- .Random.seed
runif(5)

.Random.seed <- s1
runif(5)

rngtools::RNGseed(s1)
runif(5)
```

Comment: Thank you, this was it (and more)!